# restrict search times in search box using html codes

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I made codes to search in specific items. if you write in the search box ( que ) it will show all the sentenses starting by que ,, like question1 , quesiton2 , question3 , question4 , question5

My purpose is to make search box includes 100 sentenses showing questions and answers in same sentense. and I need users to have limited time of search like making searches for 10 times only for any question they want, out of the 100 questions

those are my codes:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0055)https://www.NapesterS.com -->
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>DrNapester ALShemmari</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #0a2351;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>DrNapester - TestBank System</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Write the question here :)" title="Type in a name">
<ul id="myUL" style="display: none;">
  <li style="display: none;"><a href="Napester.html#">Question1 - (((Answer1)))</a></li>
  <li style="display: none;"><a href="Napester.html#">Question2 - (((Answer2)))</a></li>
  <li style="display: none;"><a href="Napester.html#">Question3 - (((Answer3)))</a></li>
  <li style="display: none;"><a href="Napester.html#">Question4 - (((Answer4)))</a></li>
  <li style="display: none;"><a href="Napester.html#">Question5 - (((Answer5)))</a></li>


<script>
var UL = document.getElementById("myUL");
// hilde the list by default
UL.style.display = "none";

var searchBox = document.getElementById("myInput");

// show the list when the input receive focus
searchBox.addEventListener("focus",  function(){
    // UL.style.display = "block";
});

// hide the list when the input receive focus
searchBox.addEventListener("blur", function(){
    UL.style.display = "none";
});


function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    // if the input is empty hide the list
    if(filter.trim().length < 1) {
        ul.style.display = "none";
        return false;
    } else {
        ul.style.display = "block";
    }

    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];

        // This is when you want to find words that contain the search string
     if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) { 
        li[i].style.display = "";
     } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
    } 

    // This is when you want to find words that start the search string
    /*if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().startsWith(filter)) {
        li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
    }*/
    }
}
</script>


</body></html>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome! Can you please specify what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, I see this is your first question.

I'd like to point out that your code snippet is not HTML, it is javascript.

From what I can gather from your question you want to restrict a user's ability to perform a task more than 10 times. While this would be possible in Javascript, doing this in the website front-end's may not be an appropriate design as the restriction could easily be bypassed. It is trivial for a user to modify the website's frontend code behaviour using tools like the browser's inspect element feature.

If you're satisfied in doing this in the frontend, the first consideration is that you need to know when someone has completed a search. Currently your code has no concept of when someone has finished typing their search, instead your function is called every time they type a letter in the input box because of `onkeyup="myFunction()"` .

A design change could be to modify the code to add an event listener that calls myFunction when the user hits the enter key (this could also be attached to a Search button).

Once the user hits enter, we increment a global counter variable called `guesses`. Before we search for the question, we check if the counter value exceeds 10, and if it has then the user is not permitted any more searches and a popup says that you've used up your 10 guesses.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0055)https://www.NapesterS.com -->
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>DrNapester ALShemmari</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #0a2351;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>DrNapester - TestBank System</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Write the question here :)" title="Type in a name">
<ul id="myUL" style="display: none;">
  <li style="display: none;"><a href="Napester.html#">Question1 - (((Answer1)))</a></li>
  <li style="display: none;"><a href="Napester.html#">Question2 - (((Answer2)))</a></li>
  <li style="display: none;"><a href="Napester.html#">Question3 - (((Answer3)))</a></li>
  <li style="display: none;"><a href="Napester.html#">Question4 - (((Answer4)))</a></li>
  <li style="display: none;"><a href="Napester.html#">Question5 - (((Answer5)))</a></li>


<script>
// Number of guesses the user has made
var guesses = 0

// Get the input field
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");

// Execute a function when the user presses a key on the keyboard
input.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  // If the user presses the "Enter" key on the keyboard
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    // Cancel the default action, if needed
    event.preventDefault();

    myFunction()
  }
}); 


var UL = document.getElementById("myUL");
// hilde the list by default
UL.style.display = "none";

var searchBox = document.getElementById("myInput");

// show the list when the input receive focus
searchBox.addEventListener("focus",  function(){
    // UL.style.display = "block";
});

// hide the list when the input receive focus
searchBox.addEventListener("blur", function(){
    UL.style.display = "none";
});


function myFunction() {
    guesses += 1
    if (guesses >= 10) {
        window.alert("You have used up your 10 guesses.");
        return
    }

    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    // if the input is empty hide the list
    if(filter.trim().length < 1) {
        ul.style.display = "none";
        return false;
    } else {
        ul.style.display = "block";
    }

    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];

        // This is when you want to find words that contain the search string
     if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) { 
        li[i].style.display = "";
     } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
    } 

    // This is when you want to find words that start the search string
    /*if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().startsWith(filter)) {
        li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
    }*/
    }
}
</script>


</body></html>
```

As I mentioned before, enforcing this limit in the frontend is not a great idea, because you will notice that just by refreshing the page you can reset the counter, or you could use inspect element to change the guess limit to any number you want.

[image: Inspect elementing the limit counter]

A better approach might be to have an authenticated user login on your website. When the user makes a search it reaches out to a backend server with the requested search term. The backend server keeps track of the registered users and how many searches they have made. This means that if the user refreshes the page the number of guesses they have made are still tracked.

Comment: can I show how many attempts he has to left? – 
like if he made 2 search. I want to be written in the down of search box ( 8 attempts has to be left) for example

Comment: please I just need to add one line includes below the search box includes how many attempts left like " 7 attempts to be left " ,, please help me I'm new in coding plz